# mySQL + List - how to display horizontally with flexbox

Tags: css, mysql, flexbox

I am echoing out items from a mySQL database.

I had it working perfectly using tables.

Now, I am trying to use flexbox, as apparently, tables, even though they seem perfect, are not the way to go.

I have each item in an unordered list.

The list keeps on displaying vertically for each row, I cannot get it to display across the page.

Does anyone have any simple flex-box list code?  Responsive is out the window until I get this to work!

Here's a sample from the php:

```
   while($row = $results->fetch_array()) {
       print '<section><ul class="flexcontainer"><li class="flexcontent">
                '.$row["ID"].'
            </li>';
```

Comment: Since `flexbox` can't do tabular data as good as HTML Table can (and were never meant to either), you need to provide a rendered result before we will be able to suggest a good solution. FYI, there is not such thing as _tables, even though they seem perfect, are not the way to go_, tables are so good, when used properly, that they got an _upgrade_, CSS Grid

Comment: Oh, and today one can use [**CSS Tables**](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#table-display), which can be altered as `flexbox` items or `inline-block` or .... well, almost anything

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as if you are probably looking for `flex-direction: row;` in the style of the `ul` (each item).
See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction

That being said, tables are perfectly fine for data presentation. You can even make them responsive; Try this to see what you can do:

```
table, tr, td {
    display: block;
}
```

PS: Please do include your code so nobody has to guess what you are doing and what is wrong.

Comment: _Please do include your code so nobody has to guess_...so why are you guessing then??

Comment: Because it seems like a reasonable guess ;)

Answer (score 0):

## Main answer

For the items of list to display horizontally, you will need to apply the flex properties to the list element, not the list items themselves.

If you have a `<ul>` which contains `<li>` your html could look something like this:

```
<ul style="display: flex; flex-direction: row;">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

## Additional notes

The solution given above in itself will display the items across the page but might lead to overlapping items. This can be taken care off using for example `justify-content: space-around;` which will display all the items with an equal amount of space around them. More options can be found [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

I also recommend using `flex-wrap: wrap;`, this will make sure that the items will wrap around to the next line when they reach the edge of the container.

Hope this takes care of your problems :)